# Hashmap mismatch with AssertEquals

Tags: java, junit, hashmap, equals

I have written the JUnit code to test REST POST call.

```
@Test
public  void testPOST_MAPOutput() throws IOException {
    String url="https://reqres.in/api/register";
    requestFields.put("email","eve.holt@reqres.in");
    requestFields.put("password","pistol");
    Map<String,Object> output=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    output.put("id","4");
    output.put("token","QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X4");
    System.out.println(output);
    assertEquals(output,restWebServices.doPostRequest(url,requestFields,httpHeaders, HashMap.class));

}
```

Expected and actual output seems perfectly equal still JUnit test is getting failed.

> Expected :java.util.HashMap<{id=4, token=QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X4}> 
>    Actual   :java.util.HashMap<{id=4, token=QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X4}>

Comment: Please choose your question tags more wisely. Neither your code nor the question make it clear why you've tagged your question with `assertj`.

Comment: Also, have you at least tried to find out the issue? Have you debugged your test? Have you checked what the request _really_ returns and if it really matches your expected map, especially the types?

Comment: I'll bet the `4` in the actual response is an `Integer` (or `Long`) object, not a `String`. They print the same, but don't compare as equals.

Comment: @Tom : As i am new to java what I used sysout for debugging purpose.

Comment: @Andreas : Thats really good catch. I missed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the `Map<String, Object>` notation, where you use `Object` as a value. Hence, there might be a `String`, a number (`Integer`, `Long`) or **literally anything else**, as long as its `toString()` method returns `"4"` you'll see the same prints.

For instance `String` "4" and `Integer` 4 will both print out the same number - 4, **yet they are by no means equal**!

Consider mapping to a more concrete `Object` type, for example use only `String`, and convert the result from server to `String` before adding it to the `Map` for comparison.